# Why is Tempfile#read more sensitive to utf-8 errors when explicitly told to use latin1?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, open-uri

I have a latin1 text file hosted on an http server which erroneously reports the Content-Type as "text/csv; charset=utf-8".

By default, `Encoding.default_internal` is `nil` and `Encoding.default_external` is utf-8. I know the file is latin1 so I am telling ruby to expect that, and also deal with it as such internally, using `Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.default_external = "ISO-8859-1"` (right?).

Paradoxicaly, ruby seems to trust the http server's wrong header MORE when I specify the file encoding.

```
# with this line, an exception is raised. without it, everything is fine.
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.default_external = "ISO-8859-1"

require "open-uri"
data_source = "https://example.com/foo.csv"
data_file = open data_source
data_file.charset # => "utf-8"
data_string = data_file.read # this is the line which raises an exception
```

The exception raised: `Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xC9" followed by "\xC4" on UTF-8`

What's going on here?

Comment: Can't you specify the encoding when you call `open`?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. One can only specify headers for the HTTP request. Although I'm not sure I understand your suggestion.

Comment: When you use `open` on a file, you can specify the file's encoding right in the `open` call.

Comment: gotcha. in this case it's a url.

Comment: The default does not over-ride specific (from the header). But I don't know why setting the default should have the effect you see. I'd expect the default to have no impact at all for your code.